# UITableview reload SectionHeader but not cells in section

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableview where I want to reload (and change the height of) just the sectionHeader but not the cells inside this section. The reason I want to do this is because I use the fade animation on the header, like so:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]   
    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

But at the same time I am adding a cell in that section with

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:
    @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]
    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

I'd like to be able to keep the `UITableViewRowAnimationRight` for the cell that is being added, but when I reload the Section, the fade animation gets applied to the whole section. Is there any way to just reload the sectionHeader, and not the cells in the section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create 2 separate brackets of

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

for the two insertions / changes.

Comment: Maybe your setup is different.

Comment: My setup is regular FRC + TVC. the only thing that helps is to grab views for headers and update them manually.

Comment: Doesn't work. tableView:titleForHeaderInSection is called, but the header is not updated

Comment: It seems to 'almost' work, in that the table view layout is updated, but the header doesn't update its frame until the next time you try to adjust the header height.